# In GNU Emacs, what is `[C-tab]`?

Tags: emacs, keyboard, elisp

In GNU Emacs, what is `[C-tab]`? Consider:

```
(version)
"GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600)
 of 2010-05-08 on G41R2F1"

(defun key-binding-test ()
  (interactive)
  (insert " key-binding-test called "))
```

For a single letter control character, a character constant must be used in the vector:

```
(global-set-key [C-l] 'key-binding-test) ; does not work
(global-set-key [?\C-l] 'key-binding-test) ; works
```

`?\C-l` can be evaluated  in the `*scratch*` buffer:

```
?\C-l
12
```

However to bind <kbd>C-Tab</kbd>:

```
(global-set-key [?\C-tab] 'key-binding-test) ;does not work
    ; Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-read-syntax "?")
(global-set-key [C-tab] 'key-binding-test) ; works
```

When I try to evalulate `C-tab` though:

```
C-tab ; Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable C-tab)
```

Comparing the evaluation of the vectors:

```
[?\C-l] ; input
[12]    ; result

[C-tab] ; input
[C-tab] ; result

(aref [C-tab] 0) ; input
C-tab            ; result, but C-tab can not be evaulated further.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[C-tab]` is a vector, see the manual for [vectors](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Vectors).  In there you will find that a vector is considered constant for evaluation (i.e. it evaluates to itself).

So `[C-tab]` evaluates to `[C-tab]`, a vector of one element, the symbol `C-tab`, which you can extract like so

```
(aref [C-tab] 0)
```

*Added in response to the first comment*.

Another vector is:

```
[some-symbol another (a list of things) 9]
```

it has length 4

```
(length [some-symbol another (a list of things) 9])
```

It contains two [symbols](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Symbols) `some-symbol` and `another`, a list `(a list of things)` and an integer `9`.

`C-tab` is a [symbol](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Symbols) just like `some-symbol` and `another` in the examples above, they have no value unless their [value cell](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Variables) is set to something.

Comment: And `(aref [C-tab] 0)` returns `C-tab`, which I can not evaluate. So by itself, I can't seem to look at `C-tab`, but I can use a vector of `C-tab`, `[C-tab]` with `global-set-keybinding` to bind my C-TAB key. Is `C-tab` just a symbol inside the vector, and not a value? (Don't know if that question even means anything.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Yes, it is a symbol - as I said in the second sentence.  I'll add more examples to make it clearer.

Comment: @Shannon: Also, `[C-tab]` is a syntactic shorthand to `(vector 'C-tab)` (similar to `'(C-tab)` for `(list 'C-tab)`).

Comment: From info, _(global-set-key KEY COMMAND) ... KEY is a key sequence; noninteractively, it is a string or vector
of characters or event types_. Since C-tab is not a character, and since it works, it must be an event type? So when info is talking aobut event types, they are refering to symbols that have no value, but have meaning?

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Yes, `C-tab` is an event type, you can test that with `(eventp 'C-tab)`, and find more on events in the info page for "Input Events" http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Input-Events

Comment: Thank you, now it all ties together.

Answer (score 4):

Try `(kbd "C-TAB")`, e.g. `(global-set-key (kbd "C-TAB") 'key-binding-test)`.

Keep in mind though that Tab itself is a control sequence (<kbd>C-i</kbd>), so it may not work depending on where you are. It definitely won't work on the terminal, for instance.

One thing you could try to see if emacs will even recognize C-TAB different from TAB is <kbd>C-h k C-TAB</kbd>. If the help shows you the help for just normal TAB, you're out of luck. Otherwise it'll say something like "<C-tab> is undefined".

Comment: 1) I'm trying to understand what `[C-tab]` is, I already have a way of binding to `C-Tab` with `(global-set-key [C-tab] 'key-binding-test)`

Comment: You're right that C-Tab may not always be available. For example when I log into the linux server using VT-100 emulation. It's not. But locally on a Windows XP box, it is available.

Comment: I did learn something, I had tried `(global-set-key (kbd "C-tab") 'key-binding-test)` earlier which did not work. `TAB` is case sensitive when processed by `kdb`.